# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5858 AWS SAM Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, lambda, aws-sam

I'm trying to debug locally my Lambda in vscode and I'm getting this error after:

```
Mounting C:\Users\poliian\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode\vsctkpGQtyx\output\DevHello as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
```

[image]

I'm on corporative pc and I have use a VPN, I don't know how I can configure my VPC ou SGs in my SAM template, or change this port for a good connection.

Here's my launch.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "app:lambda_function.lambda_handler (python3.9)",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "code",
                "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/app",
                "lambdaHandler": "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "runtime": "python3.9",
                "payload": {},
                "environmentVariables": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "informacoesfiscaislegais-automacaooslambdaespec:DevHello",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "template",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "DevHello"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "payload": {},
                "environmentVariables": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "informacoesfiscaislegais-automacaooslambdaespec:DevHello",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "template",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "DevHello"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "runtime": "python3.9",
                "payload": {},
                "environmentVariables": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

do I have to specify something to work or how can I solve this, please?